# How can I download one single file to a specific location?

Tags: javascript, electron

I just want to download one single file to a specific location. I don't need a listener for all downloads. I just want to download one file at the beginning of the code like

```
download(url, save_path);
```

I downloaded electron-dl, but in the documentation it only seems to be covered how to catch downloads from the renderer process. Also this seems fairly complicated [Electron - Download a file to a specific location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102851/electron-download-a-file-to-a-specific-location)

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries

Comment: Thank you! This seems to be what I was looking for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download a file with Node.js (without using third-party libraries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries)